# Dock an item on top of UITableView like imdb app on ipad?

Tags: uitableview, ipad, header, docking, imdb

I want to do something similar to the left UITableView on imdb app on ipad.
Once you have selected an item, it will become the first item on the top and it will dock there. When you flick the list below, it will always be there.
Anyone has any suggestion on how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not part of that UITableView.

It is a seperate UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell that is actually the same as in the UITableView with all the information about the selected film or character ...

When no film is selected, that second UITableView isn't visible. But as soon as you select an item, that UITableView at the top will become visible with the information about the selected item. That means that you will have to reduce the height of the UITableView (with the detail info about that item) so that the UITableView at the top will get some space for being displayed. Everytime you change the item, you need to update the UITableView using the general delegation and datasource methods for a table view. Once there's nothing selected, you just set the upper table view to hidden, and set the other table view's height to the full height.

That's all.